# Access values from UserControl after clicking on X

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a class which is a UserControl:

```
public partial class MyView : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
```

This interface has various components for user input. To show the issue I'm having, only one is needed to show, so, **`in MyView.Designer.cs`**:

```
internal System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtMyNumber;
```

This starts out as blank. So then user enters a number in the TextBox.
Then the user clicks the X in the upper right corner, which calls **`MyView.OnClose()`**:

```
protected void OnClose()
{
    string myNumber = txMyNumber.Text;
}
```

Here I want to check if any data has been entered. However, `txtMyNumber` does not show what the user entered, it is still blank. So it appears when the user clicks on the X, it is off the Form and doesn't know about the values entered.
How can these values be accessed?

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        this.OnClose();

        if (_presenter != null)
            _presenter.Dispose();

        if (components != null)
            components.Dispose();
    }

    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Comment: `Then the user clicks the X in the upper right corner, which calls MyView.OnClose():`  You should show us this code.  If it's protected, I don't know how you have that wired up.  MyView is the name of the control.  Is it the instance name, too?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Added to original question.

Comment: Are you sure that clicking the close button (that [X]) causes your OnClose method to be called.  System.Windows.Forms.Form has two overridable methods, `OnClosed` and `OnClosing`.  There are also two related events (`Closed` and `Closing`).  Generally, subscribing to the events is a better choice.  If you want to do something on the way out the door, stick with `Closing`, but the time `Closed` happens, you are too far through the door. _(This comment pre-dates the edit to the question that added the `Dispose` code)_

Comment: Dispose is too late.  Subscribe to the `Closing` event.  By the way, what are you trying to do?  Generally, once [X] is clicked, you should be getting ready to get out that door.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method is to subscribe to the container Form's **`FormClosing`** event and save what needs to be saved when the parent Form begins its *shut down* process.
The Form's event can be subscribed in the `Load()` event of the User Control, so you're sure that all the handles are already created:

```
private Form MyForm = null;

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    this.MyForm = this.FindForm();
    this.MyForm.FormClosing += this.OnFormClosing;
}

private void OnFormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("My Form is closing!");
    string myNumber = txMyNumber.Text;
}
```

This method is more useful if the UC needs to know something else about its Form.

Another, quite similar, way is to suscribe to the User Control's **`OnHandleDestroyed`** event.

```
protected override void OnHandleDestroyed(EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("I'm being destroyed!");
    string myNumber = txMyNumber.Text;

    base.OnHandleDestroyed(e);
}
```

Comment: A UserControl has a ParentForm property.

Comment: @LarsTech  Yes, sure. I was trying to be more *compatible* with other types of Controls. Anyway, `ContainerControl.ParentForm` just calls the `FindFormInternal()` method.

Comment: @Jimi: I'm trying your first suggestion. On the line `this.MyForm.FormClosing += this.OnFormClosing;` it gives the error 'MyView does not contain a definition for 'OnFormClosing'. . Also, if I comment out that line, the line above results in MyForm set to null.

Comment: `OnFormClosing` is the method right below the `OnLoad` override. You need to copy/paste everything in the first code snippet inside your control.

Comment: I did copy/past and It says 'no suitable method found to override' for `MyView.OnFormClosing(FormClosingEvenArgs`. It does accept `OnHandleDestroyed`

Comment: `OnFormClosing` is not an override. I didn't write that. It's a **private** method: `private void OnFormClosing()`

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. Regardless `OnHandleDestroyed` is viable. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, no problem. I'm glad it was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

I would try using the FormClosing event of the form to check the UserControl status.

In the UserControl, add a function, something like this:

```
public bool UserControlOK() {
  return !string.IsNullOfEmpty(txMyNumber.Text);
}
```

Then in the form, check the value in the event override:

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) {
  if (!myView1.UserControlOK()) {
    MessageBox.Show("TextBox is empty.");
    e.Cancel = true;
  }

  base.OnFormClosing(e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. If I had the `OnFormClosing` method to MyView.Designer.cs, I get compile  errors; no suitable method found to override, UserControl does not contain a definition for 'OnFormClosing'

Comment: @AlLelopath I specified the form.